# MySQL - How to join two tables without duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, join, duplicates

I have two tables like the following

```
hotels
------
hotelID
hotelName
```

Second table

```
operators
---------
opID
opName
opServices
opHotelID
```

a short explanation: In the first table I have a lot of hotels which have an increment id which is unique. The second table contains all the operators offering this hotel with additional services. The opID here is unique too but the opHotelID exists multiple times, because there can be many operators offering the hotel.

Now, what I want to get is the following:

I want to get the HotelName and an additional Column (called Operators) which lists all the operators offering the hotel.

So the result should be like this...

```
123 - Hotel ABC - OP1,Op2,OP3
```

instead of this...

```
123 - Hotel ABC - OP1
123 - HOtel ABC - OP2
123 - Hotel ABC - OP3
```

Is there a way to do this in one SQL query or how would you solve this problem? I am currently working on a search function and currently i have a simple SELECT query with a left join but this returns a lot of more rows. Now the Search should only display unique HotelIDs and combine the different Operators in one column.

Thanks for you help and have a nice day...

Bye
WorldSignia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT hotels.hotelID, 
hotels.hotelName,
GROUP_CONCAT(operators.opName SEPARATOR ', ') AS opList
FROM hotels
INNER JOIN operators 
ON operators.opHotelID = hotels.hotelID
GROUP BY(hotels.hotelID)
```

If you want to have the number of operators, you have to use COUNT on the operators ID like that:

```
SELECT hotels.hotelID, 
hotels.hotelName,
GROUP_CONCAT(operators.opName SEPARATOR ', ') AS opList,
COUNT(operators.opID) AS nbOperatos
FROM hotels
LEFT JOIN operators 
ON operators.opHotelID = hotels.hotelID
GROUP BY(hotels.hotelID)
```

Comment: Can you maybe also tell me how I can count the rows? Especially when I add a LIMIT to the query. How can I get the max rows this query produces? A simple COUNT does not work.

Comment: I edited my answer for the count option. You have to replace the inner join by a left join so it takes the hotels with no operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

you should have a simple link table, this will create the many to many relationship for many operators to a hotel

```
operatorhotels
---------
opID
opHotelID
```

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example how the query will look like when I have this extra table? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to change your DB design, you can use this query

```
SELECT hotelID,hotelName,opName FROM hotels h
INNER JOIN operators o ON  h.hotelID = o.opHotelID
GROUP BY h.hotelID,hotelName,opName
```

otherwise, create a mapping table resulting the `many to many` relation

Comment: First thans for your answer, but when I run this query it never comes to an end (i also added LIMIT 10). Both tables have approx 100k records. Is the performance just very bad or where might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP_CONCAT as already suggested. Here's the query:

```
SELECT h.hotelID, h.hotelName, GROUP_CONCAT(o.opName) 
FROM hotels h
INNER JOIN operators o ON h.hotelID = o.opHotelID
GROUP BY h.hotelID
```

Comment: Thanks, what could be the reason that this query never comes to an end ? (I tested this in mysql client on the db server)

Comment: Had some other issues with the db, needed to restart mysql. Now the GROUP_CONCAT works fine.